# File wont checkIn via rest

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, check-out, file, check-in

I created a new file in a document library. The file will usually overwrite an existing file and for that process to happen, the file will need to be checked out.

The problem is when I call the checkIn end point, the file does not checkin. Even if I call it multiple times. It does not return any error, but the file remains checked out to myself.

Here is the query I am running:

```
https://SHAREPOINTURL/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/sites/demo007/pages/default.aspx')/checkIn(comment='Checked in during migration.',checkintype=1)
```

The required headers for POST request are also in place, considering I recently created that file.

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Added the query to the question

Comment: I couldn't get to work with REST, but did not try long enough because I had a JSOM solution working, with JSOM it is ``.checkIn( [text] , [majorversion] )`` followed by ``.publish( [Text] )`` Maybe REST needs 2 calls as well?

Comment: I have chained checkIn and Publish in my code. 

    `$newFile->checkIn(trans('app.checkin_message'), 1);`
    `$newFile->publish(trans('app.checkin_message'));`
No difference

Answer (score 3):

Turns out, the comment is very important. My previous comment was `"Checked in during Migration."` I believe the extra "." was causing the issue. When I changed the checkin comment to `"Migration"`, it worked.

The **checkin** endpoint does not like any special characters including spaces. The same goes for the **approve** and **publish** endpoints. ***"Migration-Message"*** seems to work fine.

Keep the comment simple.